# Data type from datatable?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, datagridview

So i have been working on a c# application that reads data from a excel file and loads it into a Data Grid View using Data Table.

Then i wanted to insert it to a SQL Table, and i came up with a interesting question if it is possible to get the data type from the  Data Table, like whether it is int, char, time or date? So i could auto generate a SQL table according to that and then insert the data?

This is how i import data from excel to data table:

```
public void importExcel(string path, string sheetName) {
        var excel = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(path);
        excel.ReadOnly = true;
        var companies = from a in excel.Worksheet(sheetName) select a;
        var columnNames = excel.GetColumnNames(sheetName);


        DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();

        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            dtExcelRecords.Columns.Add(columnName);
        }
        foreach (var row in companies)
        {
            DataRow dr = dtExcelRecords.NewRow();
            foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
            {
                dr[columnName] = row[columnName];
            }
            dtExcelRecords.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        dataGWseznam.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to:

- Determine the data type of an input (say, from excel) - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311699/get-datatype-from-values-passed-as-string)
- Create a SQL Sever table from code - [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.create.aspx)

I think the question for me is why do you need to create the SQL Server table from the code? Usually, when importing data from excel, you know what the format of the data is (in the excel file) and you already have a SQL Server table(s) in your database where you are going to store the imported data.

If you already have a database table, the easiest way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to use the Visual Studio tools to automatically create a DataSet from your database tables. A DataSet is essentially a collection of DataTables. In your case, the DataSet would consist of just the one table you are going to be inserting into the database. You would be taking the known structured data from the import process and mapping it to your DataTable, which is built from the database table. The convenience of creating these strongly-typed DataSets using Visual Studio is that once the DataTable is populated with data from your Linq import process and the data is validated, sending that data to the database is as easy as calling:

```
yourTableAdapter.Update(yourDataTable);
```

Where the TableAdapter is created by visual studio when you created your DataSet, and is responsible for getting data to/from the database. There are tutorials all over the place for DataSets, so read up and see if it for you - [link](http://etutorials.org/Programming/ado+net/Part+I+ADO.NET+Tutorial/Chapter+13.+Strongly+Typed+DataSets/)

Lastly, I'm not sure if you have considered superior alternatives to using DataTables. You may have just stumbled across DataTables and don't know what the alternatives are. Using DataTables/DataSets/DataAdapters would be considered the 'old' way of doing things. One 'new' way of getting to and from a database would be to use Microsoft's Entity Framework. That is a massive topic in itself, so I'll let you take a look into that.

Comment: Well i used data table because im in the learning process and that was what i came across when i googled for info on how to do it.

And i want to create it from the code, because i have different excel files with different structure (more columns with different headers, etc..) so i need tables that are up to those specifications. Its easier that way than creating each table by hand.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Datasets. I started my own projects in the same way when I was learning, and came across DataSets. My project worked just fine with them. However, now that I use the Entity Framework, I would never go back. Too many benefits. 

Are the different excel files essentially for the same thing, but with just different amounts of detail? If so, I would enforce consistent header names across the files. You still only need to create one database table, and then imports with less data would just map null to fields not provided.